# Split a line after single quote into a newline

Tags: awk, sed

I have a text file like this

```
'ABC&\]D' 'DEFGH' 'QUEMKLEMEL' 'SSBJ|!KFFL'
```

and would like to convert it to

```
'ABC&\]D'
'DEFGH'
'QUEMKLEMEL'
'SSBJ|!KFFL'
```

to split the textfile at the single quotes into a newline.

The original issue is to convert a bash script from windows (the EOL characters to Unix format). I tried

```
sed 's/\r//' input >output
```

but keep getting the error when I submit the script

```
sbatch: error: This does not look like a batch script.
```

It is a long text file from windows that was transferred to linux but does not work because of the EOL characters. I tried other options to convert it so thought can subset the issue, and try it this way.

Comment: Please do add your efforts in form of code in your question, which is highly encouraged on SO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using GNU awk for it:

```
$ gawk -v FPAT="([^ ]+)|('[^']+')" -v OFS="\n" '{$1=$1}1' file
```

Output

```
'ABC&\]D'
'DEFGH'
'QUEMKLEMEL'
'SSBJ|!KFFL'
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `gnu sed` you can search for `"' "` and replace with `\n`:

```sh
sed "s/' /'\n/g" file

'ABC&\]D'
'DEFGH'
'QUEMKLEMEL'
'SSBJ|!KFFL'
```

Or using POSIX awk:

```sh
awk '{gsub(/\x27 /, "\x27\n")} 1' file

'ABC&\]D'
'DEFGH'
'QUEMKLEMEL'
'SSBJ|!KFFL'
```

or this one:

```sh
awk -F "' " -v OFS="'\n" '{$1=$1} 1' file
```

Answer (score 1):

***1st solution:*** Using `gsub` function of `awk`.

```
awk '{gsub(/\x27 \x27/,"\x27\n\x27")} 1' Input_file
```

***2nd solution:*** Could you please try following, written and tested with shown samples.

```
awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){print $i}}' Input_file
```